# How to make kramdown use conventional latex math notation (single dollar for inline and double dollar for display )

Tags: latex, markdown, jekyll, tex, kramdown

I am using kramdown in jekyll. If I need to define inline math expression I have to use double dollar notation inside paragraph like this:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur $$e^{i\theta}=\cos(\theta)+i\sin(\theta)$$
adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
```

and when I want to use display mode I have to use double dollar notation outsite of paragraph like this:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor
incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.

$$ \left[ \frac{-\hbar^2}{2\mu}\nabla^2 + V(\mathbf{r},t)\right] \Psi(\mathbf{r},t) $$

Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex
ea commodo consequat.
```

But this is ugly and it breaks LaTeX convention of single dollar for inline and double for display.

How can I force this conventional latex notation in kramdown ?

Thank you for help